# If $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ has a local minimum at $a$, then the Hessian is positive semi-definite at $a$.

Tags: matrices

Let $f\in \mathcal C^2(\mathbb R^n)$ that has a local minimum at $a$. I want to prove that the Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite at $a$, i.e. that $$x^TH(f)(a)x\geq 0$$
for all $x$. Since $f\in \mathcal C^2$, if $h\in \mathbb R^n$, there is $|\xi_h|\leq |h|$ s.t. $$0\leq f(a+h)-f(a)=h^TH(f)(\xi_h)h.$$

How can I conclude from here that $$x^TH(f)(a)x\geq 0$$
for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: Suppose $x \in \mathbb R^n$. Let $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be the function defined by  $g(t) = f(a + t x)$. Note that $0$ is a minimizer for $g$. From single variable calculus, we know that $g''(0) \geq 0$. But, $g''(0) = x^T Hf(a) x$.  So, $x^T Hf(a) x \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$. This shows that $Hf(a)$ is positive semidefinite.

Answer (score 1):

You can conclude that $x^{T}H(f)(a)x \ge 0$ for small $x$. Which shows the result for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ by definition of positive semidefinite.

EDIT : Let $\bar{x}$ be the local minimum we have 
$$ f(\bar{x} + h) = f(\bar{x}) + \frac{1}{2} h^{T} H_{f} (\bar{x})h + o(\|h\|^{2}) $$
Becuse $\nabla f (\bar{x}) = 0$.

And finally we have
$$
0 \le  f(\bar{x} + h) - f(\bar{x}) \approx_{\| h \| \rightarrow 0}  \frac{1}{2} h^{T} H_{f} (\bar{x})h
$$
EDIT3 : If $h^{T} H_{f} (\bar{x})h \ge 0$ for $\| h \| \le \delta$ then $h^{T} H_{f} (\bar{x})h$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.

EDIT2 : As I said it proves semidefinite because definite is false. For exemple the hessian of $f(x,y)= xy$ is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ which is only semidefinite.

Comment: why this show the result for all $x$ if it works for small x ?

Comment: Because $ f(a+h)-f(a)=h^TH(f)(\xi_h)h  + o(\|h\|^{2})$. Let $\bar{x}$ be the local minimum we have 
$$ f(\bar{x} + h) = f(\bar{x}) + \frac{1}{2} h^{T} H_{f} (\bar{x})h + o(\|h\|^{2}) $$
Becuse $\nabla f (\bar{x}) = 0$.

And finally we have
$$
0 \le  f(\bar{x} + h) = f(\bar{x}) \approx_{\| h \| \rightarrow 0}  \frac{1}{2} h^{T} H_{f} (\bar{x})h
$$

Comment: I don't get why this prove that $x^THf(a)x\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Because if $h^{T} H_{f} (\bar{x})h \ge 0$ for $\| h \| \le \delta$ then $h^{T} H_{f} (\bar{x})h$ for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$.